# Splitting subarrays in ruby nokogiri web scraper

Tags: arrays, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

Hello I just finished the following tutorials: https://github.com/ryandhaase/Web-Scraper/blob/master/airbnb_scraper.rb and https://medium.com/@tabor_francesca/web-scraper-airbnb-24d67939b08a#.mg7ny2tke. And I am now practicing. I am having trouble splitting subarrays. Everything works, but I cannot split the city, state and zip code into separate excel columns.

The following line is incorrect, how can I fix it?

```
city << [subarray[0], "this is not working", subarray[1]]
```

My guess is there is another line that needs to be fixed.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'


url = "https://www.tesla.com/findus/list/stores/United+States"

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.tesla.com/findus/list/stores/United+States"))   
puts page.class   

name = []
street_address = []
extended_address = []
city = []
state = []
zip = []


    page.css('a.fn.org.url').each do |line|
      name << line.text.strip
    end

    page.css('span.street-address').each do |line|
      street_address << line.text
    end

    page.css('span.extended-address').each do |line|
        extended_address << line.text
    end

    page.css('span.locality').each do |line|
        subarray = line.text.strip.split(/ · /)

        if subarray.length == 3
            city << subarray
        else
            city << [subarray[0], "this is not working", subarray[1]]
    end

  end



CSV.open("teslaStores.csv", "w") do |file|
  file << ["Name", "Street Address", "Street Address Continued", "City", "State", "Zip"]

  name.length.times do |i|
    file << [name[i], street_address[i], extended_address[i], city[i], city[i][0], city[i][1]]
  end
end
```

Comment: what's the error you're getting ?, btw, looks like you're missing an `end` to close the `if subarray.length == 3`.

Comment: What do you mean that line is incorrect and you need to fix it? What is the error? What's wrong with the result?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to do a bit more work on your question. Please read "[mcve]". We need the minimum code in your question to demonstrated the exact problem you're having, the minimal HTML in your question to show the problem, plus your expected output. If you simplify the problem/code to duplicate it odds are good you'll find the solution; remove CSV and concentrate on locating and extracting the data, then breaking it into the format you want. "[ask]" and the linked pages will also help, especially the linked pages.

Comment: Also please format your code so it doesn't require scrolling. You can do this by breaking lines up and removing unnecessary (aka most) comments.

Comment: @max pleaner - As mentioned in the question, there is no error the code passes. I need assistance in: "I am having trouble splitting subarrays. Everything works, but I cannot split the city, state and zip code into separate excel columns." When I view the output the column "city" has the data of city, state and zip code.

Comment: @fanta - adding an additional `end` causes the following error: `syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I went to a meetup.com event on python and asked one of the instructions for assistance if even though the class was not on this topic :). The teacher explained that I needed split by commas and spaces. Where before I was splitting by periods.

I had to change this:

```
page.css('span.locality').each do |line|
        subarray = line.text.strip.split(/ · /)

        if subarray.length == 3
            city << subarray
        else
            city << [subarray[0], "this is not working", subarray[1]]
    end
```

To this:

```
page.css('span.locality').each do |line|
        subarray = line.text.strip.split(',')
        subarray2 = subarray[1].split(' ')

          city << subarray[0]
          state << subarray2[0]
          zip << subarray2[1]
    end
```

Here's the full answer:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'


url = "https://www.tesla.com/findus/list/stores/United+States"

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.tesla.com/findus/list/stores/United+States"))   
puts page.class   

name = []
street_address = []
extended_address = []
city = []
state = []
zip = []


    page.css('a.fn.org.url').each do |line|
      name << line.text.strip
    end

    page.css('span.street-address').each do |line|
      street_address << line.text
    end

    page.css('span.extended-address').each do |line|
        extended_address << line.text
    end

    page.css('span.locality').each do |line|
        subarray = line.text.strip.split(',')
        subarray2 = subarray[1].split(' ')

          city << subarray[0]
          state << subarray2[0]
          zip << subarray2[1]
    end


CSV.open("teslaStores.csv", "w") do |file|
  file << ["Name", "Street Address", "Street Address Continued", "City", "State", "Zip"]

  name.length.times do |i|
    file << [name[i], street_address[i], extended_address[i], city[i], state[i], zip[i]]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a FYI, this is untested, but more idiomatic code in Ruby:

```
require 'csv'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://www.tesla.com/findus/list/stores/United+States'))   

name = page.css('a.fn.org.url').map{ |n| n.text.strip }
street_address = page.css('span.street-address').map { |n| n.text }
extended_address = page.css('span.extended-address').map{ |n| n.text }

city = page.css('span.locality').map { |n|
  subarray = n.text.strip.split(/ · /)

  if subarray.length == 3
    subarray
  else
    [subarray[0], 'this is not working', subarray[1]]
  end

}

CSV.open('teslaStores.csv', 'w') do |file|
  file << ['Name', 'Street Address', 'Street Address Continued', 'City', 'State', 'Zip']

  name.length.times do |i|
    file << [name[i], street_address[i], extended_address[i], city[i], city[i][0], city[i][1]]
  end
end
```

And that can be reduced a bit further:

```
street_address, extended_address = [
  'span.street-address',
  'span.extended-address'
].map{ |selector|
  page.css(selector).map { |n| n.text }
}
```

Comment: That code runs but doesn't solve my column issue. Do you know how to change these lines so that city, state and zip code appear in separate columns: `else
    [subarray[0], 'this is not working', subarray[1]]
  end`

Comment: The code wasn't an attempt to solve the problem, it was to get you on the right track as far as writing code that is idiomatic to Ruby development. In other words, to write it in a style that'd keep you from being taken to task by peers in a code review.